# Unexpected result converting absolute SVG 'C' command to relative 'c'

Tags: svg, bezier

I tried to get the same result converting absolute `C` commands to relative `c` coordinates for cubic Bézier curves in a SVG-path `d` attribute string.

In this test, both results should look the same. They are not.
There must be something I don't understand.

Somebody can explain what I am missing?

I know the theory and the difference between both `C` and `c`.

In my eyes the numbers are okay. The result isn't.

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="50 100 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<g id="boom" stroke="green" stroke-width="0.75" fill="lightblue"> 
   <path d="M 100,200 C 105,190 95,170 100,160 "/>
   <path d="M 150,200 c 5,-10 -10,-20 5,-10 "/>
</g>
<g id="circles" stroke="none" fill="red"> 
   <circle cx="105" cy="190" r="1"/>
   <circle cx= "95" cy="170" r="1"/>
   <circle cx="100" cy="160" r="1"/>
   <circle cx="155" cy="190" r="1"/>
   <circle cx="145" cy="170" r="1"/>
   <circle cx="150" cy="160" r="1"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: [Commands are case-sensitive. An upper-case command specifies absolute coordinates, while a lower-case command specifies coordinates relative to the current position.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d)

Comment: Don't include screenshots of code. Please add an [Minimal minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: Please [edit] your post so that it actually has a question in it. It does not go in your title, it goes in your post. The title is only to one-line summarize the problem for listing purposes. Also, [do not post pictures of test](/help/how-to-ask), just put that text directly into your post. And if it's SVG, you can even just put it in a runnable snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Your x/y calculation has an error:

The offsets to subtract from absolute values are relative to the last **on-path** position/point, so both control points and the final point are *all* relative to the same last known path point:

```
M 100 200 
C 105 190  95 170  100 160  // (M: x:-100, y:-200) 
C 105 140  95 130  100 110  // (preceding C: x:-100, y:-160)
```

becomes:

```
M 100 200 
c 5 -10  -5 -30  0 -40 
c 5 -20  -5 -30  0 -50
```

You have subtracted the two control point x/y values of the `C` command – won't work.

```css
svg{
height:20em;
overflow:visible;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="98.56 110 2.89 90">
<path id="pathPrev" 
d="M 100 200 
C 105 190 95 170 100 160 
C 105 140 95 130 100 110" 
fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" ></path>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="98.56 110 2.89 90">
<path id="pathPrev" 
d="M 100 200 
c 5 -10  -5 -30  0 -40 
c 5 -20  -5 -30  0 -50" 
fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" ></path>
</svg>
```

You can easily cross-check your calculations with online tools like

[svg path editor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/)
[svg path commander (also usable as a library)](https://thednp.github.io/svg-path-commander/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for the respons. It took a while before I knew what it meant, the words that I read, but finally it came to me.
The control points are not included (in the row of relative position  points calculations).

Comment: Pardon me, I have expressed myself in an awkward way. You might also check this post ["Convert SVG Path to Relative Commands"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179333/convert-svg-path-to-relative-commands)

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans: way better! Thanks for improving this answer.