# SVGTransform.setRotate distorts my square shape

Tags: javascript, svg

By trying to rotate a square shaped element `#sample` about its center using [`SVGTransform.setRotate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGTransform) its shape gets distorted.

```js
//REM: inserts return of getCurrentRotationOfSVGElementInDegrees(#sample) before the end of </body>
function addCurrentDegreesToBody(){
  const
    tElement = document.getElementById('sample'),
    tDegrees = getCurrentRotationOfSVGElementInDegrees(tElement).toString();

  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', `${tDegrees}<br />`)
};

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557040/svg-find-rotation-angle-of-a-path
//REM: returns the angle of passed element in degrees
function getCurrentRotationOfSVGElementInDegrees(element){
  const
    tMatrix = element.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).matrix,
    tDegrees = (180 / Math.PI) * Math.atan2(tMatrix.d, tMatrix.c) - 90;

  return tDegrees < 0 ? tDegrees + 360 : tDegrees
};

//REM: Rotates #sample by +15° about its center
function rotateBy15Degrees(){
  const
    tElement = document.getElementById('sample'),
    tAngle = getCurrentRotationOfSVGElementInDegrees(tElement),
    tMatrix = tElement.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).matrix,
    tBBox = tElement.getBBox();

  setRotationSVG(
    tElement,
    tAngle + 15,
    tBBox.x + tBBox.width / 2,
    tBBox.y + tBBox.height / 2
  )
};

//REM: sets the rotation of passed element to the passed angle about point (cx,cy)
//REM: and outputs the degrees in the <body>
function setRotationSVG(element, angle, cx, cy){
  const
    tTransform = element.ownerSVGElement.createSVGTransform(),
    tAngle = getCurrentRotationOfSVGElementInDegrees(element);

  //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGTransform
  //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform#rotate
  //REM: Rotate to passed angle (opposite of current angle plus passed angle)
  tTransform.setRotate(tAngle * -1 + angle, cx, cy);
  element.transform.baseVal.appendItem(tTransform);
  element.transform.baseVal.consolidate();

  addCurrentDegreesToBody();

  return element
};
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="1322 122 45 45" width="200px">
  <!--REM: Expected result -->
  <g id="sample" transform="matrix(0.208522,0.0256033,-0.0546508,0.445095,1023.54,-358.288)">
    <g stroke-width="0.1" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)">
      <path d="m1902.15 1045.16v-46.74h-99.72v46.74z" fill="#1e90ff" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
      <path d="m1902.15 998.42v46.74h-99.72v-46.74z" fill="none" stroke="#fff"></path>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>

<!--REM: Inline events for sample case-->
<button onclick="addCurrentDegreesToBody()">show degrees</button>
<button onclick="rotateBy15Degrees()">rotate by 15°</button>
<br /><br />
```

### show degrees

By clicking on "show degrees" the script does the following steps:

1. Calculate the current angle of `#sample` using its matrix
2. Output the angle before the end of `body`

### rotate by 15°

By clicking on "rotate by 15°" the script does the following steps:

1. Calculate the current angle of `#sample` using its matrix
2. Rotate `#sample` by +15° about its center
3. Output the new angle before the end of `body`

By doing that the shape of `#sample` distorts => is not a square anymore. The outputed angle does not show an increase of +15° which *I assume* is due to the distorting issue.

---

How am I to use [`SVGTransform.setRotate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGTransform) correctly, so that the shape of `#sample` remains a square?

---

### Update 26/08/2022

The issue seems to be the shape.

- If I use another shape like the one from enxaneta it works fine
- If I wrap the whole `#sample` in another `g` and rotate that it works fine

I can showcase this in another fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/oLej5mnf/).

Comment: In order to rotate with matrix you may try `transform="matrix( Math.cos( a ), Math.sin( a ), -Math.sin( a ),Math.cos( a ), 0, 0)` where a is the angle in radians

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick to make [`SVGTransform.setRotate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGTransform) work corretly on `#shape` is to not **append** the new transformation yet to **prepend** it by using `element.transform.baseVal.insertItemBefore()` instead of `element.transform.baseVal.appendItem()`.

Here is the working code.

```js
//REM: inserts return of getCurrentRotationOfSVGElementInDegrees(#sample) before the end of </body>
function addCurrentDegreesToBody(){
  const
    tElement = document.getElementById('sample'),
    tDegrees = getCurrentRotationOfSVGElementInDegrees(tElement).toString();

  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', `${tDegrees}<br />`)
};

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557040/svg-find-rotation-angle-of-a-path
//REM: returns the angle of passed element in degrees
function getCurrentRotationOfSVGElementInDegrees(element){
  const
    tMatrix = element.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).matrix,
    tDegrees = (180 / Math.PI) * Math.atan2(tMatrix.d, tMatrix.c) - 90;

  return tDegrees < 0 ? tDegrees + 360 : tDegrees
};

//REM: Rotates #sample by +15° about its center
//REM: and outputs the degrees in the <body>
function rotateBy15Degrees(){
  const
    tElement = document.getElementById('sample'),
    tAngle = getCurrentRotationOfSVGElementInDegrees(tElement),
    tMatrix = tElement.transform.baseVal.getItem(0).matrix,
    tBBox = tElement.getBBox();

  //REM: Center of the shape including matrix, since we insert the new rotation first we have to apply it
  const
    tOX = tBBox.x + tBBox.width / 2,
    tOY = tBBox.y + tBBox.height / 2,
    tCX = (tOX * tMatrix.a + tOY * tMatrix.c) + tMatrix.e,
    tCY = (tOX * tMatrix.b + tOY * tMatrix.d) + tMatrix.f;

  setRotationSVG(
    tElement,
    tAngle + 15,
    //tBBox.x + tBBox.width / 2,
    //tBBox.y + tBBox.height / 2
    tCX,
    tCY
  );

  addCurrentDegreesToBody()
};

//REM: sets the rotation of passed element to the passed angle about point (cx,cy)
function setRotationSVG(element, angle, cx, cy){
  const
    tTransform = element.ownerSVGElement.createSVGTransform(),
    tAngle = getCurrentRotationOfSVGElementInDegrees(element);

  //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGTransform
  //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform#rotate
  //REM: Rotate to passed angle (opposite of current angle plus passed angle)
  tTransform.setRotate(tAngle * -1 + angle, cx, cy);
  //element.transform.baseVal.appendItem(tTransform);
  element.transform.baseVal.insertItemBefore(tTransform, 0);
  element.transform.baseVal.consolidate();

  return element
};
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="1322 122 45 45" width="200px">
  <!--REM: Sample shape -->
  <g id="sample" transform="matrix(0.208522,0.0256033,-0.0546508,0.445095,1023.54,-358.288)">
    <g stroke-width="0.1" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)">
      <path d="m1902.15 1045.16v-46.74h-99.72v46.74z" fill="#1e90ff" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
      <path d="m1902.15 998.42v46.74h-99.72v-46.74z" fill="none" stroke="#fff"></path>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>

<!--REM: Inline events for sample case-->
<button onclick="addCurrentDegreesToBody()">show degrees</button>
<button onclick="rotateBy15Degrees()">rotate by 15° (setRotate)</button>
<br /><br />
```

In my environment this seems to fix already rotated or skewed shapes which have a value unequal to zero in either matrix b or c. The other shapes were not negatively affected by this change so far.

Answer (score 1):

As I've commented: in order to rotate with matrix you may try

```
transform = `matrix( ${Math.cos( t )}, ${Math.sin( t )}, ${-Math.sin( t )}, ${Math.cos( t )}, 0, 0)
```

where t is the angle in radians.
This will rotate the shape around the point x:0,y:0.

In order to rotate with matrix around it's center, or around the point you want, you need to calculate also the values for the e and f components (translate in x and y) of the matrix like in the folowing example:

```js
let x = 120,y=60;//the center of rotation
let shape = document.getElementById("matrixRotate");
let t = (15*Math.PI)/180;//angle
let a = Math.cos( t );
let b = Math.sin( t );
let c = -Math.sin( t );
let d = Math.cos( t );
let e = -x * Math.cos( t ) + y * Math.sin( t ) + x;
let f = -x * Math.sin( t ) - y * Math.cos( t ) + y;

let transform=`matrix( ${a}, ${b}, ${c}, ${d}, ${e}, ${f})`;
shape.setAttribute("transform",transform);
```

```html
<svg width="250" height="200" viewBox="0 0 250 200">
    <rect x="70" y="20" height="80" width="100" stroke="#003300" fill="#6ab150" fill-opacity="0.5">
    </rect>
    <rect x="70" y="20" height="80" width="100" id="matrixRotate" stroke="#003300" fill="#6ab150" fill-opacity="0.9" transform="">
    </rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: Both methods seem to provide the same outcome. If I use `SVGTransform.setRotate` on your `#matrixRotate` I get the result I want to as well as doing it your way. However, if I use my shape `#sample` both methods provide the same **unwanted** outcome. https://jsfiddle.net/dv0fc3pt/

Comment: Since it worked fine without `e` and `f` I assume my center of rotation being inaccurate. I am going to investigate more for now.