# SVG element shifts when using transform-origin in Firefox

Tags: html, xml, firefox, svg

So I have this blueprint that I've recreated as an SVG.

Here is the **[codepen](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/GrzmGM)**!

Everything works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox, once the rotation animation on the doors finishes, the doors themselves (the rotated elements) shift from their original positions either horizontally to the right or vertically to the bottom. In other words, applying rotation to an element with `transition` (i.e. `rotate(90deg)` ...wait... `rotate(0)`) seemingly causes the element to shift from its proper position. **Horizontal doors will shift vertically and vertical doors will shift horizontally.** Super bizarre.

The issue is most noticeable after refreshing the browser once the animation has completed.

[Here is an MVCE](https://jsfiddle.net/n9v54nro/), as per requested.

**The MVCE has been updated. It is as minimal as possible, while still producing the issue of shifting vertically and horizontally.**

```js
var fillElements = document.getElementsByClassName('f');
var fillElement;
var fillElementId;
for (i = 0; i < fillElements.length; i++) {
  fillElements[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', emphasizeRoom);
  fillElements[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', deEmphasizeRoom);
}
function emphasizeRoom() {
  fillElement = this;
  fillElementId = fillElement.id;
  changeOpacity();
  animateDoors();
}
function changeOpacity() {
  fillElement.style.opacity = '0.1';
}

function animateDoors() {
  var dashedRoomName = fillElement.id.replace(fillElementId.substring(0, 1) + '-f-', '');
  var horDoor = 'g-o-construction-shop-stage-one-door-right-top';
  var verDoor = 'g-o-construction-shop-paint-shop-door-bottom-right';
  var doorElement;

  if (horDoor.includes(dashedRoomName)) {
    doorElement = document.getElementById(horDoor);
  } else if (verDoor.includes(dashedRoomName)) {
    doorElement = document.getElementById(verDoor);
  }
  
  doorElement.style.transform = 'rotate(90deg)';
    
  setTimeout(function () {
    doorElement.style.transform = 'rotate(0)';
  }, 750);
}
  
function deEmphasizeRoom() {
  this.style.opacity = 0;
}
```

```css
svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 324px;
  top: 300px;
  transform: scale(3);
}

.o-whole, .door {
  stroke: #000;
  fill: none;
  opacity: 1;
}
  
.f {
  fill: #ff6600;
  opacity: 0;
}
  
.o-door-right-top, .o-door-bottom-right {
  transition: transform 0.75s;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
  <svg width="320" height="304" viewBox="0 0 320 304" id="svg">
    <g id="ground">
<!-- WHOLE OUTLINE -->
      <path
         id="g-o-whole"
         class="o-whole"
         d="M 108,266.5 H 98 m 55,-259 h 5 m -49,239 h 7 M 108.5,47 v -2 m 153,31 v 1.5 h 1 V 76 m -1.5,48.5 h 1.5 v 1 H 261 m 0.5,48.5 v -1.5 h 1 v 1.5 m 0,48 v -1.5 h -1 v 1.5 m -102,-31 v 1.5 h 1 V 191 m 0.5,-44.5 h -1.5 v -1 H 161 M 159.5,99 v 1.5 h 1 V 99 M 161,53.5 h -1.5 v 1 H 161 M 74.5,26 v 1.5 h 1 V 26 M 40,26.5 h 1.5 v 1 H 40 M 74.5,47 v 1.5 h 1 V 47 m -35,2 v -1.5 h 1 V 49 M 40,68.5 h 1.5 v 1 H 40 M 75.5,68 v 1.5 h -1 V 68 M 74,89.5 h 1.5 v 1 H 74 m -32,0 h -1.5 v -1 H 42 M 74.5,110 v 1.5 h 1 V 110 M 42,110.5 h -1.5 v 1 H 42 M 40.5,131 v 1.5 h 1 V 131 m 34.5,1.5 h -1.5 v -1 H 76 M 41.5,194 v -1.5 h -1 v 1.5 m 35,21 v 1.5 h -1 V 215 m -34,2 v -1.5 h 1 V 217 M 74,193.5 h 1.5 v -1 H 74 m -32,47 h -1.5 v -1 H 42 M 211.5,220 V 43 m -103,143 v -8 M 260,284.5 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m 0.5,10.5 V 269 M 211,247.5 h 18 M 211.5,239 v 28 m 35.5,-8.5 h -17.5 v -11 h 18 v 2.5 m 0,19 v -13 m -2.5,13.5 h 5 m -54,13 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m -7,-2 h 6.98438 M 196,276.5 h 7 m 1,-1 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -15,1 h 7.5 V 275 m 8,20 v -27.5 h -16 V 287 M 209,238.5 h 2.5 V 232 m -13.5,6.5 h 5 m -41,0 h 20 m -41,0 h 5 m -20,20 h 6.5 v -20 h 2.5 m -6.5,34.5 v -14 m -18,0 v 7 m 2,-7 v 7 m 2,-7 v 7 m 2,-7 v 7 m -8,-7 v 7.5 h 9.5 m -10,-8 H 97.5 V 287 m 11,-31 v 2.5 H 120 M 64.5,262 v -21.5 h 11 v 9.5 m 0,20 v 14 M 86,269.5 H 75.5 V 263 M 86,258.5 H 76 m -14,4 H 75.5 V 256 m -11,20 v -13 m 22,15 v 6.5 h -22 V 282 m 22,-15 v 5 m 0,-16 v 5 m -44,2 v 10.5 H 53 M 31.5,284 v -21 m 22,19 v 2.5 h -22 v 2.5 m 22,-16 v 5 M 53,262.5 H 7 m 46.5,2.5 v -2.5 H 56 m 53,-40 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,-33 h 7.5 V 248 m -8,-1 v -45 m -22,48 v -2.5 h 22 v 2.5 m 0,-81 v 8.5 H 104 M 94.5,161 v 16.5 H 98 M 108.5,160 v 3 M 92,151.5 h 2.5 v 9 H 108 m -13,-11 h 13.5 V 147 M 108,138.5 H 94.5 V 151 m 14,-15 v 5 M 73,170.5 H 83.5 V 152 m -11,0 v 18.5 H 62 m 19,-19 h 5 m -16,0 h 5 M 50.5,163 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 M 15,170.5 H 61.5 V 163 m -11,-9 v -2.5 H 61 M 50.5,160 v 2.5 h 11 v -11 H 64 M 28.5,151 V 140.5 H 26 m -19,11 h 10.5 v 11 H 28 m 12,0 H 50 M 39.5,160 v 2.5 h -11 v -11 h 11 v 2.5 m 69,-34 v 10 m 0,-51 v 25 m 0,-51 v 10 m 92,-55 V 20.5 H 211 m -110,13 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m 1,14 h 10.5 V 36 m 0,6 v 2.5 H 109 M 92.5,16 v 2.5 h 8 v 26 h 8 v -26 h 8 V 16 M 6.5,90 V 25 m 0,89 V 96 M 7,140.5 h 7 M 6.5,154 V 130 M 9,170.5 H 6.5 V 160 M 9,295.5 H 6.5 V 202 m 0,-16 v -15 m 25,122 v 2.5 H 15 m 92,-8 h -9.5 v 8 H 95 m -6,0 H 32 M 128.5,285 v 2.5 H 119 m 76,8 H 128.5 V 288 m 74.5,7.5 h -7.5 V 293 m 41,-5 v 7.5 H 209 m 33,-8 h -5.5 v -18 H 239 M 259.5,287 V 269.5 H 256 m 53,-240 h 4.5 v 266 h -25 v -14 h -21 v 14 h -8 v -8 H 254 m 40,-258 h 5 m -20,0 h 5 m -22,0 h 7 m -27,0 h 4 m -23,13 h 10.5 V 30 M 231,29.5 h 5 m -16,0 h 5 m -11,0 h -2.5 v 13 h 11 V 30 M 209,7.5 h 2.5 V 29 M 198,7.5 h 5 m -20,0 h 5 m -20,0 h 5 m -35,0 h 5 m -25.98959,0 H 122 m -15,0 h 9.5 V 10 m -24,0 V 7.5 h 8.5 m -32,0 H 92 M 6.5,19 V 7.5 H 47" />
<!-- FILL -->
      <path id="g-f-construction-shop" class="f"
         d="M 39,152 H 28 V 141 H 6 V 7 h 87 v 11 h 8 v 26 h 8 v 95 H 95 v 13 H 51 v 11 H 39 c 0,-3.36991 0,-7.34493 0,-11 z" />
      <path id="g-f-paint-shop" class="f"
         d="M 65,263 H 6 v -93 h 77 v -19 h 12 v 26 h 14 v 71 H 87 v 11 H 75 V 241 H 65 Z" />
      <path id="g-f-stage-one" class="f"
         d="M 133,259 H 108 V 44 h 11 V 34 H 108 V 18 h 8 V 7 h 85 v 13 h 11 v 219 h -79 z" />
<!-- DOORS -->
      <!-- horizontal -->
      <path
         id="g-o-construction-shop-stage-one-door-right-top"
         class="door o-door-right-top"
         style="transform-origin:108.5px 130.5px;"
         d="m 108,130.5 h 5.99996"
      />
      <!-- vertical -->
      <path
         id="g-o-construction-shop-paint-shop-door-bottom-right"
         class="door o-door-bottom-right"
         style="transform-origin:91.5px 151.5px;"
         d="m 91.5,151 v 5.99996"
      />
    </g>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Chrome is broken, Firefox is not. That's what RESOLVED INVALID means. What you are demonstrating is simply a bug in **Chrome**

Comment: @RobertLongson what was happening had nothing at all to do with chrome... something in my larger body of code is creating a really strange behaviour on firefox. after the door elements rotate to 90 degrees and then back to 0, for some reason their position is different from their initial position, the doors shift either vertically or horizontally, perpendicular to their direction of extension

Comment: If your MCVE does not demonstrate the issue, it's not an [mcve]

Comment: @RobertLongson Yeah, I know. It was still displaying the problem after having cleaned up much of the code. And then I continued. And when I checked it again. No problem anymore. I don't know what's causing it. I'm going to leave it for tomorrow. What could be causing behaviour like that, though, whereby an element shifts its position slightly after rotating, say, 360 degrees?

Comment: I can't explain for 360. but obviously if the centre of rotation was offset, then tan 180deg rotation could shift an element.  The same might be true if the "open" rotation had a different centre than the "close" rotation.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau The `transform-origin`, if rotated one way and then back again, should have no effect whatsoever on the position of the element. If you rotate an element, say, 90 degrees and then back to 0, it doesn't matter where the `transform-origin` is, the element should always return to its initial position just as it would if you rotated it 360 degrees. However, if the `transform-origin` changes mid-way, of course the element will shift. But the `transform-origin` was coded in the HTML, so it couldn't have been overridden.

Comment: I said if the rotate out and rotate back have **different** centres.

Comment: @Anthony Here's what I would consider a good MCVE: https://jsfiddle.net/n9v54nro/2/  But in any case it does look like a bug in FF.  I have reported it to Mozilla.  [Bug report is here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1340438)

Comment: @PaulLeBeau thanks

Comment: @PaulLeBeau any idea how i could create a workaround for something like that?? also, unmark my other quesiton as a duplicate so i can delete this one!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug in FF. [I have reported it here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1340438).

To work around this bug, you wouldn't want to use different `transform-origin` coordinates in Firefox. Because when the bug gets fixed it'll be wrong again.

The fault seems to be a rounding error in the transformation (the door shifts by 0.5 SVG units). So the obvious solution is to scale all the coordinates up so that a shift of 0.5 units won't be noticeable any more.

For instance, if you multiply the coords by 10, it seems to work (shift becomes much less noticeable). And if the bug gets fixed in the future, you won't need to change anything.

```js
var room = document.getElementById('g-f-construction-shop');

room.addEventListener('mouseenter', function animateDoors() {
  var doorElement = document.getElementById('g-o-construction-shop-stage-one-door-right-top');
  doorElement.style.transform = 'rotate(90deg)';
    
  setTimeout(function () {
    doorElement.style.transform = 'rotate(0)';
  }, 750);
});
```

```css
.o-whole, .door {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 10;
  fill: none;
  opacity: 1;
}
  
.f {
  fill: #ff6600;
  opacity: 0.1;
}
  
.o-door-right-top {
  transition: transform 0.75s;
}
```

```html
  <svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="1050 1250 200 200" id="svg">
    <g id="ground">
      <!-- ROOM OUTLINE -->
      <path class="o-whole" d="M 1085,1200 v 100" />
      <!-- ROOM FILL -->
      <rect id="g-f-construction-shop" class="f" width="1090" height="2000"/>
      <!-- DOOR -->
      <path
         id="g-o-construction-shop-stage-one-door-right-top"
         class="door o-door-right-top"
         style="transform-origin:1085px 1305px;"
         d="m 1080,1305 h 60"
      />
      <circle cx="1085" cy="1305" r="2" fill="limegreen"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

Comment: **scale the coordinates up by 10? what do you mean?** it doesn't shift the door elements by one unit, but rather a half unit. i designed my blueprint in such a way so that every line falls exactly on particular coordinates, so that if you scale it down to its original size (`scale(1)`), the smallest size, lines will still appear crisp. therefore, if it shifted the doors by one whole unit, the lines would remain crisp, yet this isn't the case. hence the elements shift by `0.5`.

Comment: i'll delete this thread as soon as you respond since you guys unmarked the other one as a duplicate

Comment: Look at the snippet in my answer. I've multiplied all the coordinates by 10.  Now in FF, the shift is barely noticeable.  And when you do the same to your original file, and render it at the normal size (instead of the zoomed version here), the shift should not be visible at all.

Comment: hm... i would then need to enlarge the `viewBox` to shrink the SVG in order to crisply display it on mobile as was intended? and would this not likely recreate the initial circumstances? i'm so baffled by this bug. i'm not sure how multiplying every coordinate by 10 (and perhaps then increasing the `viewBox` to compensate for mobile) would rectify the issue? i'm going to look into whether or not there is a way to detect which browser the user is using, and then probably simply disable rotations if that happens to be the case

Comment: It is very simple. The shifting is not by 0.5 pixels, it is by 0.5 **SVG units**.  If you multiply all your coordinates by 10 (including the viewBox as I have done above), the shift will end up being (0.5 / 10) = 0.05 of a pixel.  That's because the whole SVG document will get scaled down by 10 when rendered..  You don't have to use 10. I just chose that because it was an easy factor for manual editing. It just has to be large enough to make the effect no longer noticeable.

Comment: So counter-intuitive. You would think that if you multiplied all of the coordinates, including the `viewBox`, by 10, that the shift would either remain the same or also increase by a factor of 10. However, if I'm understanding this correctly, the shift amount remains the same: 0.5 SVG units. If I do this, I'm not even sure that all of the paths would remain crisp at a 1:1 scale. I'm also pretty sure that the doors will still become pixelated due to the shift. I'm getting paid enough to do that. 584 paths... Anyways, thanks for all of the help. I'll delete this thread as soon as you respond.

Comment: Imagine a rectangle whose sides are a length of one SVG unit.  If you scale the viewBox up by a factor of 10, that line will then be drawn a 1/10 of the size it was previously.  That's all we are doing here.

Comment: The paths should remain crisp as long as you still draw it at the same size as before. After all, all you are doing is multiplying by 10 then dividing by 10 again. And there is no need to delete this question.  It may well be useful to others who see the same bug.

Comment: yep, and therefore the 0.5 SVG unit will seem like 0.05!! sorry, i think a part of my last comment was kind of ambiguous. gonna delete this thread now in a couple minutes

Comment: alright. well there is the other thread too which is basically the samet hing idk

Comment: Oh. Did that other one I closed get reopened - or did you open a third one?  In the future, perhaps have a little more patience. :)  I would say leave both open, or delete the other one. Leave this one alone.

Comment: there's only one other one, and i requested that it be unmarked as a duplicate so that i could delete this one, since the other one is written and structured better with more info. i guess i'll just leave them both alone. the reason i couldn't wait is because this is a job that i'm doing for somebody, so it needs to be done asap. otherwise i would've just waited :p