# Rotating element in Firefox causes it to shift

Tags: javascript, html, xml, firefox, svg

I've recreated blueprints for a friend's company as inline SVGs.

Everything is fine and dandy in Chrome, but in Firefox the doors' positions shift after completing the animation. It gets even stranger. **Horizontal doors will shift downwards, whereas vertical doors will shift to the right.**

**[Here is an MVCE.](https://jsfiddle.net/n9v54nro/)**

Below is the XML for the door elements.

```
<!-- horizontal door which shifts vertically -->
<path
     id="g-o-construction-shop-stage-one-door-right-top"
     class="door o-door-right-top"
     style="transform-origin: 108.5px 130.5px;"
     d="m 108,130.5 h 5.99996"
/>
<!-- vertical door which shifts horizontally -->
<path
     id="g-o-construction-shop-paint-shop-door-bottom-right"
     class="door o-door-bottom-right"
     style="transform-origin: 91.5px 151.5px;"
     d="m 91.5,151 v 5.99996"
/>
```

The animation merely involves:

1. the application of the `transition` property in CSS
2. setting the `transform` property in JS to `rotate(90deg)`
3. then setting `transform: rotate(0)` in JS after a timeout

The animation is triggered when the rooms with the doors are hovered. In order to view the bug, you must first hover the rooms with doors and then wait until the animation completes before refreshing the page. You should be able to notice the doors shift back into place if you were paying attention.

This is such unusual behaviour, especially considering doors shift in only one direction depending on their orientation, that I'm completely baffled. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var fillElements = document.getElementsByClassName('f');
var fillElement;
var fillElementId;
for (i = 0; i < fillElements.length; i++) {
  fillElements[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', emphasizeRoom);
  fillElements[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', deEmphasizeRoom);
}
function emphasizeRoom() {
  fillElement = this;
  fillElementId = fillElement.id;
  changeOpacity();
  animateDoors();
}
function changeOpacity() {
  fillElement.style.opacity = '0.1';
}

function animateDoors() {
  var dashedRoomName = fillElement.id.replace(fillElementId.substring(0, 1) + '-f-', '');
  var horDoor = 'g-o-construction-shop-stage-one-door-right-top';
  var verDoor = 'g-o-construction-shop-paint-shop-door-bottom-right';
  var doorElement;

  if (horDoor.includes(dashedRoomName)) {
    doorElement = document.getElementById(horDoor);
  } else if (verDoor.includes(dashedRoomName)) {
    doorElement = document.getElementById(verDoor);
  }
  
  doorElement.style.transform = 'rotate(90deg)';
    
  setTimeout(function () {
    doorElement.style.transform = 'rotate(0)';
  }, 750);
}
  
function deEmphasizeRoom() {
  this.style.opacity = 0;
}
```

```css
svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 324px;
  top: 300px;
  transform: scale(3);
}

.o-whole, .door {
  stroke: #000;
  fill: none;
  opacity: 1;
}
  
.f {
  fill: #ff6600;
  opacity: 0;
}
  
.o-door-right-top, .o-door-bottom-right {
  transition: transform 0.75s;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
  <svg width="320" height="304" viewBox="0 0 320 304" id="svg">
    <g id="ground">
<!-- WHOLE OUTLINE -->
      <path
         id="g-o-whole"
         class="o-whole"
         d="M 108,266.5 H 98 m 55,-259 h 5 m -49,239 h 7 M 108.5,47 v -2 m 153,31 v 1.5 h 1 V 76 m -1.5,48.5 h 1.5 v 1 H 261 m 0.5,48.5 v -1.5 h 1 v 1.5 m 0,48 v -1.5 h -1 v 1.5 m -102,-31 v 1.5 h 1 V 191 m 0.5,-44.5 h -1.5 v -1 H 161 M 159.5,99 v 1.5 h 1 V 99 M 161,53.5 h -1.5 v 1 H 161 M 74.5,26 v 1.5 h 1 V 26 M 40,26.5 h 1.5 v 1 H 40 M 74.5,47 v 1.5 h 1 V 47 m -35,2 v -1.5 h 1 V 49 M 40,68.5 h 1.5 v 1 H 40 M 75.5,68 v 1.5 h -1 V 68 M 74,89.5 h 1.5 v 1 H 74 m -32,0 h -1.5 v -1 H 42 M 74.5,110 v 1.5 h 1 V 110 M 42,110.5 h -1.5 v 1 H 42 M 40.5,131 v 1.5 h 1 V 131 m 34.5,1.5 h -1.5 v -1 H 76 M 41.5,194 v -1.5 h -1 v 1.5 m 35,21 v 1.5 h -1 V 215 m -34,2 v -1.5 h 1 V 217 M 74,193.5 h 1.5 v -1 H 74 m -32,47 h -1.5 v -1 H 42 M 211.5,220 V 43 m -103,143 v -8 M 260,284.5 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m 0.5,10.5 V 269 M 211,247.5 h 18 M 211.5,239 v 28 m 35.5,-8.5 h -17.5 v -11 h 18 v 2.5 m 0,19 v -13 m -2.5,13.5 h 5 m -54,13 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m -7,-2 h 6.98438 M 196,276.5 h 7 m 1,-1 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -15,1 h 7.5 V 275 m 8,20 v -27.5 h -16 V 287 M 209,238.5 h 2.5 V 232 m -13.5,6.5 h 5 m -41,0 h 20 m -41,0 h 5 m -20,20 h 6.5 v -20 h 2.5 m -6.5,34.5 v -14 m -18,0 v 7 m 2,-7 v 7 m 2,-7 v 7 m 2,-7 v 7 m -8,-7 v 7.5 h 9.5 m -10,-8 H 97.5 V 287 m 11,-31 v 2.5 H 120 M 64.5,262 v -21.5 h 11 v 9.5 m 0,20 v 14 M 86,269.5 H 75.5 V 263 M 86,258.5 H 76 m -14,4 H 75.5 V 256 m -11,20 v -13 m 22,15 v 6.5 h -22 V 282 m 22,-15 v 5 m 0,-16 v 5 m -44,2 v 10.5 H 53 M 31.5,284 v -21 m 22,19 v 2.5 h -22 v 2.5 m 22,-16 v 5 M 53,262.5 H 7 m 46.5,2.5 v -2.5 H 56 m 53,-40 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,2 h 7 m -7,-33 h 7.5 V 248 m -8,-1 v -45 m -22,48 v -2.5 h 22 v 2.5 m 0,-81 v 8.5 H 104 M 94.5,161 v 16.5 H 98 M 108.5,160 v 3 M 92,151.5 h 2.5 v 9 H 108 m -13,-11 h 13.5 V 147 M 108,138.5 H 94.5 V 151 m 14,-15 v 5 M 73,170.5 H 83.5 V 152 m -11,0 v 18.5 H 62 m 19,-19 h 5 m -16,0 h 5 M 50.5,163 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 m -2,-7 v 7 M 15,170.5 H 61.5 V 163 m -11,-9 v -2.5 H 61 M 50.5,160 v 2.5 h 11 v -11 H 64 M 28.5,151 V 140.5 H 26 m -19,11 h 10.5 v 11 H 28 m 12,0 H 50 M 39.5,160 v 2.5 h -11 v -11 h 11 v 2.5 m 69,-34 v 10 m 0,-51 v 25 m 0,-51 v 10 m 92,-55 V 20.5 H 211 m -110,13 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m -7,-2 h 7 m 1,14 h 10.5 V 36 m 0,6 v 2.5 H 109 M 92.5,16 v 2.5 h 8 v 26 h 8 v -26 h 8 V 16 M 6.5,90 V 25 m 0,89 V 96 M 7,140.5 h 7 M 6.5,154 V 130 M 9,170.5 H 6.5 V 160 M 9,295.5 H 6.5 V 202 m 0,-16 v -15 m 25,122 v 2.5 H 15 m 92,-8 h -9.5 v 8 H 95 m -6,0 H 32 M 128.5,285 v 2.5 H 119 m 76,8 H 128.5 V 288 m 74.5,7.5 h -7.5 V 293 m 41,-5 v 7.5 H 209 m 33,-8 h -5.5 v -18 H 239 M 259.5,287 V 269.5 H 256 m 53,-240 h 4.5 v 266 h -25 v -14 h -21 v 14 h -8 v -8 H 254 m 40,-258 h 5 m -20,0 h 5 m -22,0 h 7 m -27,0 h 4 m -23,13 h 10.5 V 30 M 231,29.5 h 5 m -16,0 h 5 m -11,0 h -2.5 v 13 h 11 V 30 M 209,7.5 h 2.5 V 29 M 198,7.5 h 5 m -20,0 h 5 m -20,0 h 5 m -35,0 h 5 m -25.98959,0 H 122 m -15,0 h 9.5 V 10 m -24,0 V 7.5 h 8.5 m -32,0 H 92 M 6.5,19 V 7.5 H 47" />
<!-- FILL -->
      <path id="g-f-construction-shop" class="f"
         d="M 39,152 H 28 V 141 H 6 V 7 h 87 v 11 h 8 v 26 h 8 v 95 H 95 v 13 H 51 v 11 H 39 c 0,-3.36991 0,-7.34493 0,-11 z" />
      <path id="g-f-paint-shop" class="f"
         d="M 65,263 H 6 v -93 h 77 v -19 h 12 v 26 h 14 v 71 H 87 v 11 H 75 V 241 H 65 Z" />
      <path id="g-f-stage-one" class="f"
         d="M 133,259 H 108 V 44 h 11 V 34 H 108 V 18 h 8 V 7 h 85 v 13 h 11 v 219 h -79 z" />
<!-- DOORS -->
      <!-- horizontal -->
      <path
         id="g-o-construction-shop-stage-one-door-right-top"
         class="door o-door-right-top"
         style="transform-origin:108.5px 130.5px;"
         d="m 108,130.5 h 5.99996"
      />
      <!-- vertical -->
      <path
         id="g-o-construction-shop-paint-shop-door-bottom-right"
         class="door o-door-bottom-right"
         style="transform-origin:91.5px 151.5px;"
         d="m 91.5,151 v 5.99996"
      />
    </g>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: unmark it as a duplicate and i'll delete the other question. this one is structured way better

Comment: I think there's an ongoing issue with transform-origin https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1209061 maybe use rotate with a specified center (eg 'rotate(90,150,150)' ) if thats possible.

Comment: @ian that seems to be a different issue and is in any case a Chrome bug (hence its closure as invalid in the Firefox bugtracker).

Comment: @Ian it is a FF bug, and has been posted [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1340438). if i used `rotate(90deg, Xpx, Ypx)` wouldn't that simply disrupt it in FF and the other browsers in which it works perfectly fine??

Comment: @Ian correction: "wouldn't that simply [fix it in FF but disrupt it for the] other browsers in which it works perfectly fine?

Comment: Quite likely, which is why I suggested an alternate approach and not use transform-origin at all.

Comment: @Ian aren't the 2nd and 3rd parameters an `offset` to the `transform-origin`, though, and not a `transform-origin` in and of themselves??

Comment: If you set it as an attribute, rather than css, it ignores that. So instead of <path style='transform...'/> you can do <path transform="rotate(90,108.5,130.5)"/> or element.setAttribute ... (note style takes cascading precedence over attributes, so you would need to remove the transform style). So it depends if there is a specific reason to use style over attributes, if not, for this particular case, I would be tempted to use it.

Comment: @Ian although i'll muck around with it and see what happens, i don't think i'll end up trying that because i'm fairly certain it will mess up the `transform-origins` for all of the other browsers in which it actually works. thanks for sharing though. paul suggested increasing everything by a factor of 10, including the `viewBox`, so that the 0.5 SVG units is really like 0.05. god, there's 600 paths tho :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It turns out it's a bug in Firefox:** https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1340438

Comment: See the [original question posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42262474/svg-element-shifts-when-using-transform-origin-in-firefox), for more discussion on this.