# Expand SVG Coordinates Path

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, arrays

```
  <path transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,600)" stroke-width=".074" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" stroke="#a56752" d="M666.84 101.05V101.07 101.05L666.83 101.04V101.03H666.82 666.62 666.61L666.6 101.04V101.05 101.59 101.6L666.61 101.61H666.62 666.82 666.83V101.6L666.84 101.59V101.56 101.59 101.6L666.83 101.61 666.82 101.62H666.62L666.61 101.61 666.6 101.6 666.59 101.59V101.05L666.6 101.03 666.61 101.02H666.62 666.82 666.83L666.84 101.03V101.05"/>

  <path transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,600)" stroke-width=".074" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" stroke="#a56752" d="M 666.84 101.05 L 666.84 101.07 L 666.84 101.05 L 666.83 101.04 L 666.83 101.03 L 666.82 101.03 L 666.62 101.03 L 666.61 101.03 L 666.6 101.04 L 666.6 101.05 L 666.6 101.59 L 666.6 101.6 L 666.61 101.61 L 666.62 101.61 L 666.82 101.61 L 666.83 101.61 L 666.83 101.6 L 666.84 101.59 L 666.84 101.56 L 666.84 101.59 L 666.84 101.6 L 666.83 101.61 L 666.82 101.62 L 666.62 101.62 L 666.61 101.61 L 666.6 101.6 L 666.59 101.59 L 666.59 101.05 L 666.6 101.03 L 666.61 101.02 L 666.62 101.02 L 666.82 101.02 L 666.83 101.02 L 666.84 101.03 L 666.84 101.05 "/>
```

**Above path transform are identical to each other**, just one of it displays it in a **more simplified manner which includes (L, V, H)** which stands for vertical and horizontal. **May I ask how to expand the simplified version(First Line) into a more expanded form version (Second Line) ?** I have a hard time understanding the path transform to expand it as shown in the second Line? Any help will be very appreaciated, I really want to try to understand :).

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/svg-path-syntax-illustrated-guide/ ,   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

Comment: This is a nice tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IY-xTCFjiM

Comment: Are there any existing-code to convert this to the expanded form, else I will have to write the code?

Comment: @MisterJojo, this is pretty confusing haha :)

Answer (score 0):

Commands like `V`, `H`, `S` and `T` are commonly referred to as **shorthand commands** since they repeat or reflect a previous command property.

#### Horizontal or vertical shorthands `H` and `V`

```
M0 10 L50 10 L50 100
```

equals

```
M0 10 H50 V100
```

`V` and `H` will take the previous command's x or y values to draw a vertical or horizontal line.

`S` and `T` are cubic or quadratic curve shorthands reflecting previous `C` or `Q` control points.

#### Convert shorthands to "lonhghands"

Many svg libraries (e.g. [fontello svgpath toolkit](https://github.com/fontello/svgpath), [svg path commander](https://thednp.github.io/svg-path-commander/index.html)) include conversion methods.

I'm using [`getPathData()` polyfill](https://github.com/jarek-foksa/path-data-polyfill) (based on the [official working draft](https://svgwg.org/specs/paths/#InterfaceSVGPathData))

##### 1. Quick solution: Normalize via `getPathData({normalize:true})`

`getPathData()` has a normalize option, that converts all commands to:

- all absolute
- quadratic `Q`, `T` and `A` (arctos) are converted to cubic `C` commands
- cubic shorthands `S` become `C`
- implicit/repeated commands are also decomposed: `L 100 100 150 15` => `L 100 100 L 150 15`

  let pathData = path.getPathData({normalize:true});
  path.setPathData(pathData)

##### 2. Convert shorthands to longhand notation (retain quadratic or arc)

The conversion is applied in 2 steps:

- conversion to absolute commands via `pathDataToAbsolute()` helper
- `pathDataToLonghands()` loops through all commands and adds/calculates missing coordinates for longhands

```js
let pathData = path.getPathData();
// decompose shorthands
pathData = pathDataToLonghands(pathData);
path.setPathData(pathData)
outputLong.value = path.getAttribute('d')


// normalized to cubics
let pathDataCubic = path.getPathData({
  normalize: true
});
pathDataCubic = roundPathData(pathDataCubic, 2);
path.setPathData(pathDataCubic)

outputNorm.value = path.getAttribute('d')


/**
 * round pathData
 */
function roundPathData(pathData, decimals = 3) {
  pathData.forEach((com, c) => {
    if (decimals >= 0) {
      com.values.forEach((val, v) => {
        pathData[c].values[v] = +val.toFixed(decimals);
      });
    }
  });
  return pathData;
}



/**
 * decompose/convert shorthands to "longhand" commands:
 * H, V, S, T => L, L, C, Q
 * reversed method: pathDataToShorthands()
 */
function pathDataToLonghands(pathData, decimals = -1) {
  pathData = pathDataToAbsolute(pathData, decimals);
  let pathDataLonghand = [];
  let comPrev = {
    type: "M",
    values: pathData[0].values
  };
  pathDataLonghand.push(comPrev);

  for (let i = 1; i < pathData.length; i++) {
    let com = pathData[i];
    let type = com.type;
    let values = com.values;
    let valuesL = values.length;
    let valuesPrev = comPrev.values;
    let valuesPrevL = valuesPrev.length;
    let [x, y] = [values[valuesL - 2], values[valuesL - 1]];
    let cp1X, cp1Y, cp2X, cp2Y;
    let [prevX, prevY] = [
      valuesPrev[valuesPrevL - 2],
      valuesPrev[valuesPrevL - 1]
    ];
    switch (type) {
      case "H":
        comPrev = {
          type: "L",
          values: [values[0], prevY]
        };
        break;
      case "V":
        comPrev = {
          type: "L",
          values: [prevX, values[0]]
        };
        break;
      case "T":
        [cp1X, cp1Y] = [valuesPrev[0], valuesPrev[1]];
        [prevX, prevY] = [
          valuesPrev[valuesPrevL - 2],
          valuesPrev[valuesPrevL - 1]
        ];
        // new control point
        cpN1X = prevX + (prevX - cp1X);
        cpN1Y = prevY + (prevY - cp1Y);
        comPrev = {
          type: "Q",
          values: [cpN1X, cpN1Y, x, y]
        };
        break;
      case "S":
        [cp1X, cp1Y] = [valuesPrev[0], valuesPrev[1]];
        [cp2X, cp2Y] =
        valuesPrevL > 2 ? [valuesPrev[2], valuesPrev[3]] : [valuesPrev[0], valuesPrev[1]];
        [prevX, prevY] = [
          valuesPrev[valuesPrevL - 2],
          valuesPrev[valuesPrevL - 1]
        ];
        // new control points
        cpN1X = 2 * prevX - cp2X;
        cpN1Y = 2 * prevY - cp2Y;
        cpN2X = values[0];
        cpN2Y = values[1];
        comPrev = {
          type: "C",
          values: [cpN1X, cpN1Y, cpN2X, cpN2Y, x, y]
        };

        break;
      default:
        comPrev = {
          type: type,
          values: values
        };
    }
    pathDataLonghand.push(comPrev);
  }
  return pathDataLonghand;
}


function pathDataToAbsolute(pathData, decimals = -1, unlink = false) {
  // remove object reference
  pathData = unlink ? JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(pathData)) : pathData;

  let M = pathData[0].values;
  let x = M[0],
    y = M[1],
    mx = x,
    my = y;
  // loop through commands
  for (let i = 1; i < pathData.length; i++) {
    let cmd = pathData[i];
    let type = cmd.type;
    let typeAbs = type.toUpperCase();
    let values = cmd.values;

    if (type != typeAbs) {
      type = typeAbs;
      cmd.type = type;
      // check current command types
      switch (typeAbs) {
        case "A":
          values[5] = +(values[5] + x);
          values[6] = +(values[6] + y);
          break;

        case "V":
          values[0] = +(values[0] + y);
          break;

        case "H":
          values[0] = +(values[0] + x);
          break;

        case "M":
          mx = +values[0] + x;
          my = +values[1] + y;

        default:
          // other commands
          if (values.length) {
            for (let v = 0; v < values.length; v++) {
              // even value indices are y coordinates
              values[v] = values[v] + (v % 2 ? y : x);
            }
          }
      }
    }
    // is already absolute
    let vLen = values.length;
    switch (type) {
      case "Z":
        x = +mx;
        y = +my;
        break;
      case "H":
        x = values[0];
        break;
      case "V":
        y = values[0];
        break;
      case "M":
        mx = values[vLen - 2];
        my = values[vLen - 1];

      default:
        x = values[vLen - 2];
        y = values[vLen - 1];
    }

    // round coordinates
    if (decimals >= 0) {
      cmd.values = values.map((val) => {
        return +val.toFixed(decimals);
      });
    }
  }
  // round M (starting point)
  if (decimals >= 0) {
    [M[0], M[1]] = [+M[0].toFixed(decimals), +M[1].toFixed(decimals)];
  }
  return pathData;
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 2em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 50%;
}

textarea {
  min-height: 20em;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" class="svgPreview" viewBox="3 7 80 70">
<path id="path" d="M3,7 L13,7 m-10,10 l10,0 V27 H23 v10 h10C 33,43 38,47 43,47 c 0,5 5,10 10,10S 63,67 63,67 s -10,10 10,10Q 50,50 73,57q 20,-5 0,-10T 70,40t 0,-15A 5,5 45 1 0 40,20 a5,5 20 0 1 -10,-10Z" fill="#cccccc" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="butt"></path>
 </svg>

<h3>Longhand output</h3>
<textarea id="outputLong"></textarea>

<h3>Normalized output (only M, L, C, Z)</h3>
<textarea id="outputNorm"></textarea>

<p>Svg by @Phrogz: http://phrogz.net/svg/convert_path_to_absolute_commands.svg
</p>
<p>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677885/convert-svg-path-to-absolute-commands#9677915</p>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/path-data-polyfill@1.0.4/path-data-polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

You could also play around with [my experimental custom version of `getpathData()`](https://github.com/herrstrietzel/svgHelpers/blob/main/js/pathData.getPathDataCustom.js) polyfill.
It adds some helper functions for conversion tasks like absolute to relative, shorthands to longhands, rounding etc.

```js
let pathData = path.getPathDataOpt();
// decompose shorthands
path.setPathData(pathData)
outputLong.value = path.getAttribute('d')

// convert to optimized: all relative, rounded
let options = {
  relative: true,
  decimlas: 1
}
let dMin = getDopt(pathData, options);
outputMin.value = dMin
```

```css
body {
  padding: 2em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 50%;
}

textarea {
  min-height: 20em;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" class="svgPreview" viewBox="3 7 80 70">
<path id="path" d="M3,7 L13,7 m-10,10 l10,0 V27 H23 v10 h10C 33,43 38,47 43,47 c 0,5 5,10 10,10S 63,67 63,67 s -10,10 10,10Q 50,50 73,57q 20,-5 0,-10T 70,40t 0,-15A 5,5 45 1 0 40,20 a5,5 20 0 1 -10,-10Z" fill="#cccccc" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="butt"></path>
 </svg>

<h3>Longhand output</h3>
<textarea id="outputLong"></textarea>

<h3>Shorthand and relative output</h3>
<textarea id="outputMin"></textarea>

<p>Svg by @Phrogz: http://phrogz.net/svg/convert_path_to_absolute_commands.svg
</p>
<p>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677885/convert-svg-path-to-absolute-commands#9677915</p>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/herrstrietzel/svgHelpers@main/js/pathData.getPathDataCustom.js"></script>
```