# Javascript equivalencies of C language (*, f, -> and some more)

Tags: javascript, c, svg, geometry

I found a code [from internet](http://devmaster.net/forums/topic/4947-transforming-an-ellipse/) and try to understand it. I don't know what is the programming language of the code and try to find javascript equivalencies or workarounds.

A) Which language is in question?

---

```
*a_offsetrot = PI / 4.0f;
```

B) What is the meaning of '*' in above and what is the possible Javascript equivalence?

C) What is the meaning of 'f' and what is the possible Javascript equivalence?

---

```
if (K<0) K = 0; else K = (float)sqrt (K);
```

D) What is the meaning of '(float)' and what is the possible Javascript equivalence?

---

```
*a_offsetrot = 0.5f * (float)atan2(B,ac);
```

E) What is the meaning of "atan2" and what is the possible Javascript equivalence?

---

```
void Ellipse_Transform (float * a_rh, float * a_rv, float *a_offsetrot, Vector2 * endpoint, matrix * a_mat, int *a_ReverseWinding)
```

F) What is the meaning of 'Vector2 * endpoint' and is there possible Javascript equivalence? Is Vector2 a thing that has two (x,y)-points or only one (x,y)-point?

---

```
m[0] = a_mat->m[0] * +rh * c + a_mat->m[3] * rh * s;
```

G) What is the meaning of 'a_mat->m[0]' and what is the possible Javascript equivalence?

### EDIT: Updated title to be more meaningful.

EDIT2: Thanks to constructive answer of [@rid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13136379/1691517) I got the C language code translated to Javascript and it is [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13102801/1691517) and full working functional example is [HERE](http://jsbin.com/oqojan/73).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A) The language is C.

B) `*` is the dereferencing operator. There is no equivalent in JavaScript, since JavaScript does not use pointers.

C) The `f` in `4.0f` indicates that the value is a `float` value. There is no equivalent in JavaScript, since in JavaScript all numeric values are represented as numbers.

D) `(float)` is a type cast. Something similar in JavaScript is `parseFloat()` which will parse the argument and return a floating point number, but this is different from type casting, and there is no equivalent to type casting in JavaScript.

E) `atan2()` is a math function for calculating the arctangent. You can find it in the standard JavaScript `Math` package.

F) A `Vector2` is most likely a structure that has two properties, an `x` property and a `y` property.

G) `a_mat->m[0]` means the first element from the array `m` that is a property of `a_mat`. If `a_mat` was an object in JavaScript, the equivalent would be `a_mat.m[0]`.

Comment: Is Vector2 "native" C type or does it come from some additional library or package?

Comment: @Timo, it's not native, it's most likely defined as a `struct` by the person who wrote that code, and used as a convenient way to store 2 values together. You can think of it as an object in JavaScript: `{x: ..., y: ...}`.

Comment: Why atan2? Why not atan?

Comment: @Timo, there's also an `atan()` function that takes a single argument. `atan2()` returns the arctangent of the quotient of its arguments. `atan()` returns the arctangent of a number. The JavaScript `Math` package [contains both of these functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math#Methods).

Comment: Fine. Thanks. I understand now the code more perfectly!

Comment: Is `atan2` more suitable for handling bitmap graphics where y-axis increases downwards?

Comment: @Timo, you should ask that as a separate question.

Comment: The * operator can be so multiply and dereferencing operator. When converting the above code to Javascript, can I just remove all dereferencing operators?

Comment: @Timo, sure, since JavaScript doesn't have pointers, there's nothing to dereference. `*` has many meanings (it can be a pointer type, the dereferencing operator or the multiplication sign), but in that particular case, it's the dereferencing operator.