# SVG Path and Transformation

Tags: javascript, svg

I have an svg path element that is flipped and when I insert it into the document I have to transform it using `transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 0)"`. When this statement is executed, does the SVG Path element's data commands get transformed? Can I successfully get the new data commands, if it creates one, after the transformation? Or like I assume, the path element's data command remain the same.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the path "data command", perhaps the 'd' attribute? In that case yes, if you query `path.getAttribute('d')` then you will get the same result as in an untransformed element.

Comment: yeah the d attribute. I basically would like to get the updated version after translation or scale, or rotation etc.

Comment: You will have to apply the transformation to the path, there are various related questions in the "related questions" sidebar.

Comment: I applied the transformations but the transformation doesn't change the d attribute of the path. Not sure if it's possible yet

Comment: Yes, it does not change the d attribute. You need to use a library or code it yourself, as is detailed in related answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149301/baking-transforms-into-svg-path-element-commands?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this little online tool:
http://treebuilder.de/svg/transformer/index.html
for a quick result.