# Adjust origin of SVG graphic

Tags: android, svg, android-vectordrawable

**tl;dr**: Given arbitrary SVG `<path>` how can I adjust the path commands to set a new origin for the file?

### Details

I'm using Adobe Illustrator to create vector graphics for use in Android. **Illustrator has [a bug](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/15401/2413)** where under (unknown) circumstances the `viewBox` and all coordinates created for your graphics do not match the coordinates you set for the canvas and objects in Illustrator. Instead of (for example) `viewBox="-7 0 14 20"` you might get `viewBox="-53 75 14 20"`. Usually the the path commands will be translated to fit inside that viewBox. Sometimes even that fails.

In a normal SVG file (a) this would rarely even be noticeable, and (b) it would be easy to fix by wrapping everything in a root-level `<g transform="translate(46,-75)">`. In an Android [`VectorDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html) this requires an extra `<group>` that I don't want to add, and (unlike SVG) I can't add a translate to the `<path>` itself. And in my code, the origin matters.

How can I adjust the path commands for all the paths in an SVG file to offset them by a fixed amount, allowing me to place the origin where I'd like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*A* solution is to add explicit `transform="translate(…,…)"` onto each path that you want to adjust, view the SVG in a web browser, use the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5149301/405017) [note: my own] to bake the translate into the path data, and then use the Web inspector to get the changed values. Cumbersome.

---

**Better**: I've created a little online tool [SVG Reoriginizer](http://phrogz.net/SVG/svg_reoriginizer.html) [no ads, no revenue] that lets you paste SVG code into the top box, click (or use alt+shift+arrow keys) to adjust the origin, and see the translated path commands shown in the bottom.

The core code is this function, which offsets the viewBox and all absolute path commands by the specified amount, and returns the changed SVG as a string:

```js
function offsetOrigin(svg,dx,dy){
  svg.viewBox.baseVal.x -= dx;
  svg.viewBox.baseVal.y -= dy;
  [].forEach.call(svg.querySelectorAll('path'),function(path){
    var segs = path.pathSegList;
    for (var i=segs.numberOfItems;i--;){
      var seg=segs.getItem(i), c=seg.pathSegTypeAsLetter;
      if (/[MLHVCSQTA]/.test(c)){
        if ('x'  in seg) seg.x -=dx;
        if ('y'  in seg) seg.y -=dy;
        if ('x1' in seg) seg.x1-=dx;
        if ('x2' in seg) seg.x2-=dx;
        if ('y1' in seg) seg.y1-=dy;
        if ('y2' in seg) seg.y2-=dy;
      }
    }
  });

  return (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(svg);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Phrogz. This could be an excellent tool, but I found it only shifts my viewBox and clipPath coordinates and none of the other polygons in the SVG.

Comment: @MSC This code may not work without a polyfill for browsers like Chrome that have deprecated some of the SVG interfaces.

Comment: Ah. Beyond my capabilities, I'm afraid.

Comment: @msc I'll try to check on it and fix if needed tonight. Will ping you when I do.