# Getting SVG d after transform

Tags: svg, vector, graphics

I Have a square SVG that I want to create into a diamond, rotating it 45 degrees gives me the effect I want but I am limited to only using the `d` value of an SVG for my image. How can I get the newly transform `d` value  from https://jsfiddle.net/x2v3tmdp/

In other words here is my d: `M13,14H2c-0.5523,0-1-0.4477-1-1V2c0-0.5523,0.4477-1,1-1h11c0.5523,0,1,0.4477,1,1v11C14,13.5523,13.5523,14,13,14z`  now I need to rotate that 45 degrees and get the new d value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to process an SVG file to remove all the transforms and bake them into the path data, [you can use svgo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329125/removing-transforms-in-svg-files) for that.

If you want to do it in code yourself, [Timo's anser on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149301/baking-transforms-into-svg-path-element-commands) should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would add transform matrix so the `d` values do not need to change

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-10 -5 20 35">
 <g fill="none" stroke-width="1px">
  <path stroke="black" transform="matrix(1.000000,0.000000,0.000000,1.000000,0.000000,0.000000)" d="M13,14H2c-0.5523,0-1-0.4477-1-1V2c0-0.5523,0.4477-1,1-1h11c0.5523,0,1,0.4477,1,1v11C14,13.5523,13.5523,14,13,14z"/>
  <path stroke="blue" transform="matrix(0.707107,0.707107,-0.707107,0.707107,0.000000,0.000000)" d="M13,14H2c-0.5523,0-1-0.4477-1-1V2c0-0.5523,0.4477-1,1-1h11c0.5523,0,1,0.4477,1,1v11C14,13.5523,13.5523,14,13,14z"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

[image: preview]

Where the transform represents 3x3 homogenuous transform matrix:

```xml
transform="matrix
  (
  x_scale*cos(x_ang),x_scale*sin(x_ang),
  y_scale*cos(y_ang),y_scale*sin(y_ang),
  x_offset,y_offset
  )"
```

where `x_ang`  is your rotation angle of x axis, `y_ang=x_ang+90deg` is rotation angle of y axis (if not perpendicular to x then you got skew), `x(y)_scale` is the scale in each axis (`1.0`) and `x(y)_offset` is the origin of new coordinate system in the parent coordinate system so you can use ti to translate/pan stuff.