# How to remove all transforms from text elements in an SVG with Inkscape

Tags: svg, inkscape, svg-transforms

How do I remove all `transform` from text elements in an SVG while keeping the text elements and the font size in place?

This question is similar to [Removing transforms in SVG files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13329125), but this question her specifically addresses **text elements**.

I already tried the usual trick to ungroup everything, cut everything, delete the current layer and past everything again in place. But the transforms are kept. I also tried and installed the Inkscape extension https://github.com/Klowner/inkscape-applytransforms. However it only works for paths not for text elements.

Note, I must not convert the text elements into paths, because I need the SVG as a template for FreeCAD and FreeCAD requires the `<svg:text>` element in order to replace the text content.

I can also provide a sample file.

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of a graphic application it makes sense to prefer/keep transformations as long as possible when manipulating elements.

Otherwise the application would constantly need to recalculate multiple attributes like

- x,y, dx, dy
- width, height
- font-size, line-height
- stroke-width

etc

Keep in mind these recalculations would quickly lead to **rounding errors** – so editing your elements will soon lead to a **loss of information**.

Besides, `<text>` elements don't have a seperate attribute for rotation – yes, there is actually `rotate` but it's actually just a shorthand for a transformation.

### JavaScript transformation converter

Provided your text is not rotated, you could recalculate transformations like `translate`, `scale` to harcoded presentation attribute values.

```css
svg{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width:10em;
}

textarea{
  width:100%;
  min-height:20em;
}
```

```html
<p><button onclick="removeTextTransforms();">Remove text transforms</button></p>
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <text x="10" y="50" font-size="10" paint-order="stroke" font-family="sans-serif" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" transform="scale(1.2) translate(10, 20)">Text</text>
</svg>

<textarea id="output"></textarea>

<script>
  function removeTextTransforms() {
    let texts = document.querySelectorAll('text');
    texts.forEach(el => {
      let parent = el.farthestViewportElement;
      // check elements transformations
      let matrix = parent.getScreenCTM().inverse().multiply(el.getScreenCTM());
      let {
        a,
        b,
        c,
        d,
        e,
        f
      } = matrix;
      // round matrix
      [a, b, c, d, e, f] = [a, b, c, d, e, f].map(val => {
        return +val.toFixed(3)
      });
      let matrixStr = [a, b, c, d, e, f].join('');
      let isTransformed = matrixStr !== "100100" ? true : false;
      if (isTransformed) {
        // matrix to readable transform functions
        let transObj = qrDecomposeMatrix(matrix);
        let scale = (transObj.scaleX + transObj.scaleY) / 2;
        // convert transforms to attributes
        let {
          translateX,
          translateY,
          rotate
        } = transObj;
        let x = +el.getAttribute('x')
        let y = +el.getAttribute('y')
        let fontSize = +el.getAttribute('font-size')
        if (rotate) {
          return false
        } else {
          // scale stroke-width
          scaleStrokeWidthText(el, scale);
          el.setAttribute('x', (x * scale + translateX));
          el.setAttribute('y', (y * scale + translateY));
          el.setAttribute('font-size', (fontSize * scale));
          el.removeAttribute('transform');
        }
      }
    });
    
    output.value = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg)
  }

  function scaleStrokeWidthText(el, scale) {
    let styles = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    let strokeWidth = styles.getPropertyValue('stroke-width');
    let stroke = styles.getPropertyValue('stroke');
    strokeWidth = stroke != 'none' ? parseFloat(strokeWidth) * scale : 0;
    el.setAttribute('stroke-width', strokeWidth);
    el.style.removeProperty('stroke-width');
  }
  /**
   *  Decompose matrix to readable transform properties 
   *  translate() rotate() scale() etc.
   *  based on @AndreaBogazzi's answer
   *  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107134/find-the-rotation-and-skew-of-a-matrix-transformation#32125700
   *  return object with seperate transform properties 
   *  and ready to use css or svg attribute strings
   */
  function qrDecomposeMatrix(matrix, precision = 3) {
    let {
      a,
      b,
      c,
      d,
      e,
      f
    } = matrix;
    // matrix is array
    if (Array.isArray(matrix)) {
      [a, b, c, d, e, f] = matrix;
    }
    let angle = Math.atan2(b, a),
      denom = Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2),
      scaleX = Math.sqrt(denom),
      scaleY = (a * d - c * b) / scaleX,
      skewX = Math.atan2(a * c + b * d, denom) / (Math.PI / 180),
      translateX = e ? e : 0,
      translateY = f ? f : 0,
      rotate = angle ? angle / (Math.PI / 180) : 0;
    let transObj = {
      translateX: translateX,
      translateY: translateY,
      rotate: rotate,
      scaleX: scaleX,
      scaleY: scaleY,
      skewX: skewX,
      skewY: 0
    };
    let cssTransforms = [];
    let svgTransforms = [];
    for (let prop in transObj) {
      transObj[prop] = +parseFloat(transObj[prop]).toFixed(precision);
      let val = transObj[prop];
      let unit = "";
      if (prop == "rotate" || prop == "skewX") {
        unit = "deg";
      }
      if (prop.indexOf("translate") != -1) {
        unit = "px";
      }
      // combine these properties
      let convert = ["scaleX", "scaleY", "translateX", "translateY"];
      if (val !== 0) {
        cssTransforms.push(`${prop}(${val}${unit})`);
      }
      if (convert.indexOf(prop) == -1 && val !== 0) {
        svgTransforms.push(`${prop}(${val})`);
      } else if (prop == "scaleX") {
        svgTransforms.push(
          `scale(${+scaleX.toFixed(precision)} ${+scaleY.toFixed(precision)})`
        );
      } else if (prop == "translateX") {
        svgTransforms.push(
          `translate(${transObj.translateX} ${transObj.translateY})`
        );
      }
    }
    // append css style string to object
    transObj.cssTransform = cssTransforms.join(" ");
    transObj.svgTransform = svgTransforms.join(" ");
    return transObj;
  }
</script>
```

You might also try this [experimental codepen helper](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/yLEBbqY)  I recently created to strip as many (nested) transform as possible.